# plotly hover with lots of data in it does not show

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I noticed when a plotly has lots of data, the standard hover label sometimes does not show.

The issue seems to be that, when the height of the label box is greater than the space available in the plot, it will simply not show. Is there any workaround for this ? (e.g. enable scrolling for the hover box, or simply show the data until it fits in the box).

To make clear what I mean, consider this reproducible example, based on one of the examples of the official docs for the python API (https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/):

```py
import plotly.express as px

df_2007 = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
df_2007 = df_2007.assign(**{f"{col}_dup1": df_2007[col] for col in df_2007.columns})
df_2007 = df_2007.assign(**{f"{col}_dup2": df_2007[col] for col in df_2007.columns})

fig = px.scatter(
    df_2007,
    x="gdpPercap",
    y="lifeExp",
    log_x=True,
    hover_name="country",
    hover_data=df_2007.columns,
)

fig.show()
```

This is pretty much the same code as in the original example, but I duplicated the columns of the dataset a couple of times, just to give plotly a lot of data to show in the hover box. When you run this code, you will see it will not render the hover box for the points towards the top of the plot. It shows only for the points towards the bottom of the plot, and the hover box takes the whole vertical space in the plot.

So, it seems to be that, when the height of the box is greater than the available space from the y coordinates to the top of the plot, then it will not render.

To check this might be the issue, you can try and set the font size, thereby making the hover box smaller. In this case, the hover will show again for all points.

```py
fig.update_layout(hoverlabel=dict(font_size=8))
```

Not shown here, but I also tried using the `plotly.graph_objects` interface, and it's the same story.

And the issue should be the height of the box. If I include the data using `hovertemplate`, but making sure it does not include new lines for every variable, but separating them by a comma for example, the hover will show in all points. It's just that the hover box will be a looooonnngggg line, so not really useful. But in that case, plotly does not have any issues accommodating the same amount of data in the box, letting the box grow horizontally as necessary.

Is there any way to achieve a similar behaviour, but letting the hover box grow vertically?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may depend on your personal environment, but I tried running your code as-is in jupyterlab and it didn't show any hover data at the default graph height. Then I set the graph height to 1000 and all hover data was displayed in a vertical line. `fig.update_layout(height=1000)`

Comment: [The graph I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wtwK.png)

Comment: thx. Sure, I think you are right that of course it depends on the settings you use. And your example illustrates the issue quite well. When you used the default height of the plot, the hover box was probably too large to fit in the plot area and therefore it does not render for any point. When you enlarge the plot area, now it fits and the hover box shows again. So this is very similar to the example I put in the question. I just tweaked the font size to make the hover box smaller. You achieved something similar, by enlarging the plot itself.

Comment: so, the issue indeed seems to be the relative height of the hover box and that of the plot. My question was trying to find a way to convince plotly to always render the hover box, regardless of its size (just show only the data that fits, or let it scroll, or whatever, but prevent to just stop showing the hover box). Having said that, after what I have seen in the docs and in other posts, there does not seem to be a way to do that for an arbitrary data size in the hover box.

Comment: Of course, the most straightforward way to solve the issue is just to limit the amount of data to be shown in the hover box. That can be easily accomplished using the hovertemplate, or just limiting the data passed to plotly.

Comment: I too do not believe that hoverboxes have the ability to automatically increase the size of the graph based on the content. It can't work for every situation, but assuming, for example, that the height of a single line of hover text is 20 pixels, you might be able to set the graph height to the number of hover lines multiplied by the number of hover lines. `fig.update_layout(height=20*len(df.columns)`

Comment: thx, that could be useful as well. Meanwhile, I am just limiting the number of columns to show, and also making use of the <extra></extra> tag, that displays data in the secondary box. That covers 99.9999999% of the use cases for us. Thanks again mate!